# Integrating Member Mouse with Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I'd be **very grateful** for any help you might be able to offer me & any other Zapier + Member Mouse users out there.

I want to create a sequence in Zapier that begins with a tag being set by a CRM. The sequence looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgwi4.png). After a tag is set, I want a [bundle](https://support.membermouse.com/support/solutions/articles/9000020237-bundles-overview) applied to a member in Member Mouse (a bundle is protected content, 'applying' it gives the member access). This [can be done](https://support.membermouse.com/support/solutions/articles/9000020241-getting-started-with-the-membermouse-api) using the Member Mouse Api & example Python is given by Member Mouse below:

```
import pycurl

# api credentials
apikey = 'XdC3YOh'
apisecret = 'gkxbLEY'
membership_level_id = '4'
affiliate_id = 'someaffiliate'

# user details
userfirst = 'John'
userlast = 'Smith'
useremail = 'johnsmith@email.com'

# parameters
params = (
    'apikey=' + apikey
  + '&apisecret=' + apisecret
  + '&membership_level_id=' + membership_level_id
  + '&affiliate_id=' + affiliate_id
  + '&first_name=' + userfirst
  + '&last_name=' + userlast
  + '&email=' + useremail)

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.YOURURL.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php?q=/createMember')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, params)
c.setopt(c.FAILONERROR, True)

try:
    c.perform()
except pycurl.error, error:
    errno, errstr = error
    print 'An error occurred: ', errstr
```

I am not a developer, and can't get this working. I have been in touch with Zapier support, who sent me here. Please can I therefore ask you:

1) How do I set up the Code Zap?

[Image of the code zap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHBI3.png)

2) Why the sample code generates an error (with the correct keys)? SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 32)

3) How do I set up the Put Zap or is it even needed in this sequence?

[Put Zap - image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh9D5.png)
[Put Zap - image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2N9b.png)

Many thanks in advance!

:)

p.s - apologies for all the links, I do not have enough points to post images.

Comment: Hey Zaki, I am a Zapier user however I have not used / heard of Member Mouse. That said I do often use Zapier to connect in a similar fashion to other APIs. The first issue here is that Zapier does not support the 'import pycurl' line at the very beginning of the code. I would instead recommend using the requests library. Beyond this I am not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate on what you mean by: 'I want to create a sequence in Zapier that begins with a tag being set by a CRM'. Does this mean you are looking to use that event as a trigger?

Comment: Hi xavdid, thanks for your reply. Is there a particular approach you would take with the request library? re. your question: the tag would be set by Drip (email provider) when a user does something. So, Drip would be used as a trigger within the Zap (as you imply), then the rest of the Zapier workflow changes a membership level on Membermouse or something like that (setting up product access etc).